# AngularJS dynamic element ID and DOM access

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom

On my code I create a an element with a dynamically generated ID. Afterwards, from my controller I'm trying to populate that same element, but it seems that to the controller that element doesn't exist.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

(html)

```
<div class="pd_graph" ng-controller="pd.controller" id='cont-{{ my_context }}'>
</div>
```

(AngulaJS controller)

```
$scope.my_context = "test";
$('#cont-'+ $scope.my_context).html("<h2>Hello world</h2>");
```

My expected result would be something like:

```
<div class="pd_graph" ng-controller="pd.controller" id='cont-test'> 
<h2>Hello world</h2>
</div>
```

Is there ANY way to do this? So far when I try to access $('#cont-'+ $scope.my_context) it simply doesn't exist.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try wrapping your jQuery code with `$timeout`. Also using using jQuery for DOM manipulation in AngularJS is a bad idea (without a good reason for it). You should use Directives that have jQLite

Comment: The DOM doesn't render right after you set your variable, use a timeout.

Comment: I've already tried the $timeout option. For some reason it simply ignores the delay and executes the function straight away.

Will look into the Directives thing...

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I did, and it didn't help :(

Comment: I would argue that you should be creating this element with angular, not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector needs to use `#` for `id` attributes. Your id already starts with it - `#cont-test`. I suggest you change it to `cont-test`.
Then wrap any jQuery code in a `$timeout` function, otherwise the id will not be rendered yet (jQuery is not part of AngularJS digest cycle).

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.my_context = "test";
  $timeout(function() {
    $('#cont-' + $scope.my_context).html("<h2>Hello world</h2>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="pd_graph" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div id="cont-{{my_context}}">replace me</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you're right regarding the "#" on the ID. I've corrected the code on my question.